# showing mysql_error message with jQuery dialog

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, function

Is it possible to show the mysql_error (if exists) with jQuery dialog?

```
$query="UPDATE user SET pass=(SELECT MD5('$pass')) WHERE userid='$userid'"
$result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
```

i mean something like a own function inside `mysql_error()`

i searched the whole internet before this question :o)

best regards

Comment: jQuery Dialog runs on the client, mysql_error() runs on the server.

Comment: yes i know. also when the error is displayed on the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

In short: **No** because as Barmar noted `jQuery Dialog` runs on **client** and `mysql_*` runs on **server**.

If you really need to display error do the following:

1. Have an **AJAX** call to your update function
2. `$result = mysql_query($query) OR echo(mysql_error());`
3. On your **AJAX** return just **append** returned message into JQuery Dialog's Body

Other solution would be to just log those errors somewhere in database or in files and dont display any **mysql** related errors to user.

**TIP:** get rid of **mysql_*** functions they are deprecated and switch to **PDO** or **MySQLi**

Comment: tnx for fast response.. but when i have an error the error will be displayed directly to my frontend for example "Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\#alt2\login_php_v1.3\test.php on line 25" and doesn't look very nice in the site! i know i can turn off the messages but i dont wont it. just want to display the frontend error message into a dialog

Comment: If you use AJAX, nothing is displayed unless the Javscript chooses to display it, and it can put the output into a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.  There are a few things to note, though.

1. You must have a way of initiating the MySQL query from the client side. Usually, this is done via AJAX and is triggered by a browser event. In the below example I used a button click event to trigger the AJAX routine.
2. The AJAX routine will "call" your PHP file and initiate your DB query. Optionally, you can pass parameters to the PHP side. In this example, I am passing a userName that a user may have entered into a form field.
3. Any output from the PHP file (hopefully, it would be useful data) will appear in the AJAX routine's `success:` function. You must process it *there* (i.e. insert data into the DOM, etc), within in that function and no where else. As you can see, my code takes whatever is received (variable `whatigot`) and uses the `.html()` method to inject it into the `<div id="err_msg">`.
4. Finally, the jQUI dialog is the easiest bit - just run the .dialog method against that div. Note that the 2nd and 3rd references in the `<head>` are what make it work (the **jqueryui** refs).

Here is a stand-alone example using the AJAX method:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#mybutt').click(function() {
                    var someGuy = $('#sumuser').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "your_php_file.php",
                        data: 'userName=' + someGuy,
                        success: function(whatigot) {
                            //alert('Server-side response: ' + whatigot);
                            $('#err_msg').html(whatigot);
                            $('#err_msg').dialog({
                                autoOpen:true,
                                width:500,
                                title:"Your Error Message",
                            });
                        } //END success fn
                    }); //END $.ajax
                }); //END button click event


            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    Type a user name and then press Go:<br />
    <input type="text" id="sumuser">
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Go">

    <div id="err_msg"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Note that PHP processing is done in an external file, which I reference above as `your_php_file.php`.  This is what is inside that. On my system, it generates a MySQL error -- you may need to tweek the MySQL query to generate an error.

YOUR_PHP_FILE.PHP -- actually, must be named in same case as is referenced, so really: your_php_file.php:

```
//echo 'Got to the PHP side';

$phpSideUserName = $_POST['userName'];

$query="UPDATE users SET pass=(SELECT MD5('$pass')) WHERE userid='$phpSideUserName '"
$result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
```